# Multi Value control on TFS 2017 U3 on-premises after upgrade

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

We upgrade our TFS test environment from 2015.1 to 2017.3 .
We have Multi Value control in our Work Items, after the upgrade the Work Item form was empty (unless the tags), and the error on the console was about the multi value control. I downloaded the Multi Value extension from the market place, but is only for the new form (WebLayout), and we not want to move to the new form yet.

I go to Legacy Extensions and disable the old multi value control extension, and now we the work item is appear, unless the fields with the multi value ("Cannot create work item control of type "MultiValueControl"). I saw on the [old extension website](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=witcustomcontrols) that have a newer version of this (1.3.2.5) but I didn't find a download to this file anywhere. Is there a way to make the multi value work on the old form? or we must to use the new form?

Comment: It's highly recommended, for multiple reasons, to upgrade to the new form.

Comment: The old control can probably be made to work with 2017 with some effort though.

Comment: I succeed to use the old form with the old Multi Value control, but as you suggest, we will move to the new form. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this control: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control

Customize for xml: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-multivalue-control/blob/master/xmldetails.md

Comment: Thank you. I already tried this, but it only for the new form (WebLayout) and not for the old form.

Comment: If you download archive of [controls](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=witcustomcontrols) you`ll get all sources and releases. Also you may find description for last release:    "Id": "0",
    "Name": "1.3.2.5",
    "DevelopmentStatus": "Stable",
    "Description": " Updated Webaccess multivalue control to support *TFS 2017 Update 1 RC1* old workitem form.",
    "ReleasedDatge": "",
    "ModifiedDate": "",
    "Files": [
      {
        "Id": "",
        "FileName": "WitCustomControlSetup2015-1.3.2.5.zip",
        "Url": "./0/13722540-73d2-4fc3-9d82-194db9989d7c",

      }
    ]

Comment: Thanks. I tried to upload the release from the archive, but it's says that "invalid zip". I think we will move to the new form.. Thanks again!

Comment: Moving to new form is the best solution. Because tfs 2018 does not support the old form. But I`ve renamed "releases\0\13722540-73d2-4fc3-9d82-194db9989d7c" to "111.zip" and I`ve got two files in it: CodePlex.WitCustomControls.MultiValueControl.zip and WitCustomControlSetup2015.msi.

Comment: Great! I changed the name to something.zip, and I installed the CodePlex.WitCustomControls.MultiValueControl.zip, it's fix the problem. Thanks. We probably will move to the new form, but now we do not have to.