# How to open Work Item in browser using VS 2019 Team Explorer?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, tfs-workitem, team-explorer

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 to do some testing on our code base ready for migrating from Visual Studio 2017, I am also testing to ensure it plays nicely with our TFS system (currently TFS 2018 on premises).

It looks as though the Visual Studio Work Item Form is back! (VS 2017 dropped support for this in favour of opening Work Items in a web browser). I've not managed to find any information on this. I like the fact that we might have the option to work with Work Items in the VS IDE as well as the web browser, however its return introduces a few issues:

- We use a custom MultiValue control that does have support for the VS 2019 Team Explorer (it last worked in VS 2015). Do you know where I can get hold of a MultiValue control that will work on the Work Item form in the VS 2019 Team Explorer?
- Given that the MultiValue control isn't working I would like to continue working with Work Items in a browser. The VS 2019 Team Explorer seems to favour opening Work Items within the IDE, how can I open them in a browser from within the VS 2019 Team Explorer? Better still, how can I configure it to open in a browser by default?

Is there a better place for me to ask these questions?

Comment: While Team Explorer lists work items here, when opened (right click | Open or double click) they open in the browser. (I've not checked the new work item ability because this is a working project...)

Comment: For me they open in Visual Studio, not in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Work Items should default to opening in the web in Visual Studio 2019.  That behavior has not changed from Visual Studio 2017.

There is an option under "Tools->Options->Work Items" to enable the "Legacy experience (compatibility mode)".  It sounds like that option has somehow gotten enabled in your installation.  If you switch that back to "Default experience", work items should open in the web.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That option was already set to "Default experience". I tried changing it to "Legacy experience (compatibility mode)", closed and re-opened VS, and it made no difference. Changed it back to "Default experience" and repeated - still no difference.

Also, my Team Explorer looks the same as it did in VS 2017 regardless of the setting. I don't see the new Work Items "experience" shown in screenshots I've seen elsewhere. I wonder if I'm encountering a VS/installation bug.

Comment: That is bizarre indeed.  You might try repairing the Visual Studio install.  If that doesn't help, can you please use the "Send Feedback" feature in Visual Studio 2019 (Help->Send Feedback->Report a Problem) to report this?  Please include screenshots.  Once the issue is created in Developer Community, I can help route it to the team that owns Work Item Tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience. This is a designed behavior right now.

Please take a look at this similar issue:  [TFS work items opened inside Visual Study no longer open in the web browser, they always open in the Visual Studio editor](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/539058/tfs-work-items-opened-inside-visual-study-no-longe.html)

> *According to the response from MSFT:*
>
> We have re-design the default landing page for work items in Visual
>   Studio 2019 which only works with server >= 2019. **If server is <
>   2019, work items will be open in Visual Studio only**.

Since you are using TFS 2018 with VS2019, you may have to open work item in web portal from browser directly right now. Otherwise, you have to upgrade your TFS version from 2018 to Azure DevOps 2019, if you insist on opening the work item in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are due to upgrade TFS later this year so that should move us forward a bit. Are you able to provide any hints on where I might find (or how I might create) a MultiValue control for use within the Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: Hi Rob, usually it's used for new form (WebLayout). But work item in Visual Studio IDE is still using the old  Layout forms. You may give a try with the workaround mentioned in the comment of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850897/multi-value-control-on-tfs-2017-u3-on-premises-after-upgrade If this still not work , I'm afraid you have to  move to web portal or upgrade your TFS version.

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry this is by designed. There is no workaround at the moment. You may have to upgrade TFS version to fix this issue in Visual Studio.